# Collapse multiple options with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm looking for a classy way to collapse help messages for boolean toggles in
argparse. For example this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("booleans")

parser.add_argument('--no-store', action='store_false',
                    help="Don't do it'")
parser.add_argument('--store', action='store_true',
                    help="Do it")

parser.print_help()
```

prints:

```
usage: booleans [-h] [--no-store] [--store]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  --no-store      Don't do it'
  --store         Do it
```

But I've got a whole bunch of boolean flags, what I'd really like is to be able to write it in a way that makes it print:

```
usage: booleans [-h] [--[no-]store]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  --[no-]store    Do or don't do it.
```

Is there any nice way for me to collapse arguments, and provide custom help
text and option names?

Comment: It would probably be easier to have only a `--store` option with a boolean argument.

Comment: @larsmans In some ways that would be easier, in as much as I actually know how to do it. I'd *rather* do it this way, though, if anyone can figure out a way how.

Comment: This way `--store --no-store` would be valid input.

Comment: That's true, but with an option that takes an argument `--store y --store n` would be valid input, which is fine.

Comment: Custom usage takes care of the first line.  In the help part, set `help` of the affected arguments to `SUPPRESS`, and put your own help in the `description`.

Comment: @hpaulj that would mean writing all of the help that argparse would normally write for me, right? That's a decent solution, if tedious for something the size that I was working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `usage` parameter to the `ArgumentParser` and write your own syntax line.

Answer (score 1):

```
usage = ['booleans [-h]']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("booleans",usage=usage[0],
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

grp1 = parser.add_argument_group(title='Boolean arguments',description='')
def foo(group, name, help):
     # create a pair of arguments, with one 'help' line
     group.add_argument('--no-'+name, action='store_false', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
     group.add_argument('--'+name, action='store_true', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
     usage.append(' [--[no-]%s]'%name)
     group.description += "[--[no-]%s]\t%s.\n"%(name,help)
foo(grp1, 'store', "Do or don't do it",)
foo(grp1, 'remove', "Do or don't do it",)
parser.usage = ''.join(usage)
parser.print_help()
```

produces

```
usage: booleans [-h] [--[no-]store] [--[no-]remove]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

Boolean arguments:
  [--[no-]store]    Do or don't do it.
  [--[no-]remove]   Do or don't do it.
```

I use `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` to allow use of`\t`.  It would also allow a multiline description (other pairs of arguments).

With the `SUPPRESS` it really doesn't matter whether the arguments are in `grp1` or `parser`.